# php and js script combined

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to include the following code in my wordpress, sending the username to Heap Analytics, if user is logged in.

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?> 
<script>
var usr_heap = <?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); echo $current_user->display_name; ?>;
heap.identify({'Wordpress Username': usr_heap});
</script> 
<?php } ?>
```

Any idea what I'm possibly doing wrong? Probably a very simple question...
Thanks for your help!
V

Comment: your missing quotes around the php tag `var heap = "<?php .... ?>";`

Comment: What does the JS console/ error log say?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `usr_heap` is a string, so there must be `" "` around the sting value

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { 
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
?> 
<script>
var usr_heap = "<?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?>";
heap.identify({'Wordpress Username': usr_heap});
</script> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Hemnath! Unfortunately, that does not yet make a difference. Maybe there is something else?!?

Comment: How can a JSON key has space - `'Wordpress Username'` ? Are you sure, this is fine??